# How to check if extract contains - Imacro Javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

This is in IMacros using the javascript side.

the extract ealier in the script will extract "You will arrive in Dallas, Texas in (1-20) seconds!.

However the macro will not know how many seconds this is when checking the extract, It would work if it runs If contains "You will arrive"

```
var extract=iimGetLastExtract();
if(extract.toLowerCase()!="you will arrive in dallas, texas in * seconds!")
{
 iimDisplay("Still Travelling")
}
else
{
 iimDisplay("Finished travelling")
```

The * does not work and it says its travelling even when its needed to say Finished?

Comment: You're trying to use * as a wildcard inside of a string. You need to use a regular expression to do this. Right now it's looking for the actual character '*', not a number from 1-20.

Comment: How would i check for a number between 1-20 as the answer would be different on every run?

Comment: You need to use a regular expression to do this. There is lots of documentation out there on how they work.